# How to use store Controller method in Laravel, when class extends another?

Tags: php, laravel

I have class User that has variables like name, surname, email... and classes Student and Teacher that extend User. Let's just focus on Student class.

I want to create student (create so that he's in database) with:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('students.store') }}">
@csrf
        <div>
            <x-input-label for="name" :value="__('Name of student')" />
            <x-text-input id="name" type="text" name="name" :value="old('name')" autofocus />
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('name')" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

        ...

        <x-primary-button>
             {{ __('Create') }}
        </x-primary-button>
</form>
```

But the problem is, there are no name, surname... variables in Student class, they are in User class. Laravel tries to put everything in SQL table students. (Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list')

What do I have to do? How to create objects of classes that inherit from other classes in Laravel?
Maybe extend students table in database so that it has these variables?

edit: Student class may have variables like: classes, frequency...

Comment: Should it save in a table called `students`, should it is not? It not really clear what the behavior should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Student class extends the User class, you need to specify the table the Student class is using, otherwise, Laravel has to guess the table name based on the model name.

```
protected $table = 'users';
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#table-names

Edit --

Say you have a Users table like so:

| id | name | surname | is_student |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | doe | 0 |
| 2 | jane | smith | 1 |

And a classes table:

| id | class | room |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Geometry | A |
| 2 | Physics | B |

You can connect them via a pivot table (classes_users) to store additional student-specific data:

| student_id | class_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

Comment: I editted the post. If I did the thing you wrote there would be a problem when I'd like to add classes, frequency... to the Student instance and store it, right?

Comment: I you are saving data specific to students that isn't recorded on the users table, you will need another table. If you need to give a student a class, you may have a table of classes that you could connect to the user/student through an intermediate table ("classes_students").

Comment: See if my edit makes sense.

Comment: In order to implement this, do you have to create model classes_users in laravel project, or just create classes_users table in database?

Comment: You just need the table. Laravel will look for a table matching the class names that it expects to be related. Note: class names are always listed alphabetically when creating the pivot table unless specifically set otherwise.